# What is "being " doing in "Human Being"?

Tags: word-usage

For me "Human **Being**" doesn't make sense. "Being human" however makes sense to me. Is that a one-off word?

Also it is not used when referring to organisms other than humans, like "tiger being" etc..

So, what exactly is "being" doing up there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collocation '*human being*' is not an exception or anything special, because the noun '**being**' means '**a living creature**' and may be used with other adjectives, not necessarily with the adjective 'human'. For example,

> a *strange being* from another planet

So, 'human being' probably confused you because you haven't realized that 'being' is a noun in that context, and 'human' is not a noun here, but an adjective.

By the way, I came across a little bit more specific definition of the noun 'being': *a real or imaginary living creature, especially an intelligent one*. So, I guess that might be the reason why we wouldn't say 'tiger being'.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct **but** different. In the first, *being* is a noun and in the second, *being* serves as a verb!

The words *Human being* ***collectively*** form a noun (compound noun?). You got confused because you thought of a noun *being* in *human being* separately.

> [Human being *(noun)* -](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/human+being) *a member of any of the races of Homo sapiens; person; man, woman, or child*

On the other hand, *being human* is *verb + noun*. Consider...

> ***Being a businessperson,*** I don't want to take a risk on this half-baked deal.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, any word ending in "-ING" is a VERB traditionally, as long as the ING is a suffix to it and the base word a verb, as in "BE-ING". It is also to be known that a nomilized word is not a noun in its actual form, rather, it's a noun by function. A proper research on grammatical names and functions might help.
I stand to be corrected.